# Validating Google emailId and redirect to an error Page

Tags: identityserver4, blazor

We have our company email configured with gmail. I wanted to show an error page to the user if they try to login with any gmail id not registered in our system. How do I redirect to an error page with two redirect uri's. one fore trying to login again (Challenge Google) and one to go back to the main application (Blazor Page)?

Answer (score 0):

have you take a look at this doc?
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html#handling-the-callback-and-signing-in-the-user

specifically the **Inspecting the external identity** section